# AWS DynamoDB using CreateBatchWrite

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

Using .net core c# dynamo db

I was using the following method to save to my dynamo db:

```
public Task SaveAsync(T item)
{
    return base.SaveAsync(item, _config);
}
```

And then in my controller I call the above as:

```
foreach (var data in myData)
{
   //update data
  await _dynamoDbManager.SaveAsync(data);
}
```

The above works fine but instead of saving individually I want to save at one using batch.

I dont know how I can write a similar Batch method. I tried with below:

```
public Task CreateBatch()
{
   //The below is not correct as I dont know what to pass as <T> in below call.
   return CreateBatchWrite<T>(_config);
}
```

I want to create the above method so that I can use it as below in my controller:

```
var batchWriter =  CreateBatch();
foreach (var data in myData)
{
   //update data
}
batchWriter.AddPutItems(myData);
await batchWriter.ExecuteAsync();
```

Can anyone help in writing my CreateBatchWrite method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create method as:

```
public BatchWrite<T> CreateBatch<T>()
{
   return CreateBatchWrite<T>(_config);
}
```

And then call this in your controller as:

```
var batchWriter =  CreateBatch<MyData>();
batchWriter.AddPutItems(myData);
await batchWriter.ExecuteAsync();
```